# Storing System::StartTime in SSIS to a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working in SQL Server 2008 and BIDS (SSIS).  I have an execute SQL task in my SSIS package which runs the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.LoadHistory (LoadDate)
VALUES        (?)
```

The dbo.LoadHistory.LoadDate column is a datetime data type in SQL.  The ? placeholder returns the parameter System::StartTime, which I have set to be a DBTIMESTAMP data type.

SSIS throws an error, stating that it is an invalid time format.  I have tried switching this parameter to DBDATE, but that doesn't work.  Do I need to do something to System::StartTime in order to store it in my LoadDate column?

Comment: Don't create duplicates of your questions. Just edit the existing one

Comment: Sorry about that.  I posted a comment on that thread, but I didn't see a follow-up.  So, I thought that I exceeded the comment limit, since the site asked me if I wanted to move it to a conversation instead.  Also, I narrowed my problem down to a data type issue.  So, it's no longer a question about getting my parameters right, but more about data types (I'm assuming).